# Use '#' char in Angular routes path

Tags: angular, routes

Is it possible to define routes in Angular using `#`?

Instead of having:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

to have it like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '#home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

In this case, if it is to take local development server as example, the URL would be `localhost:4200/#home` instead of `localhost:4200/home`.
I know that `#` is used for fragments, but I'm trying to use it in route definition.

**Update**
The use case is to perform a migration between web technologies and preserve the old URLs.

Comment: This is the common way: https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy. A hash directly on route name starts has no sense for me?

Comment: This is now the same. This strategy assumes that the route is `localhost:4200/#/home`

Comment: Really the same? A hash in the link is a bookmark. A hash beween slashes stop the browser refresh (needed for older browser)

Comment: Sorry, for the typo. I wanted to say "this is not the same".

Comment: Doesn't look like a valid path to me.

Answer (score 1):

Then we talk the same. This is not possible, because:

[image]

Read all about it [here](https://docs.angular.lat/guide/router#base-href-1).

The last part (part with hash at start of link) is a fragment. So it jump to a bookmark on a site as example. You can set this things in Angular:

```
changeFragment() {
  this.router.navigate( [ '/home' ], { fragment: 'part' } )
}
```

This will look like: `http://localhost:4200/home#part`

I don't know will it helps you. But a custom name with hash inside is technically not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to create a catch all route then redirect them properly - so that way if the route doesn't match send it to a component that can remove the # like so. then invoke the angular router to redirect to the proper string.  make sure when you generate this component you generate it as standalone true, you will need to import the routerModule into that component.

this is kind of an ugly work around but it will work and prevent you from getting 301 redirect errors.

I originally did not understand your question.

on **app-routing.module.ts**

//make this your last line of your router, this will catch all routes that don't have a match, so that way you can keep the original hash then reroute it inside a component.

```
{path:'**', loadComponent:()=>import('yourcomponentpath/redirectComponent.component').then((c)=>c.redirectComponent)
```

on **redirect-component.component.ts**

```
constructor(private router:Router);

ngOnInit(){
 const route = this.router.url[0];
 this.reWrite(route)
 
}
    function reWrite(routeName:string){
      const  route = routeName;
      const routesliced = route.slice(1);
      return this.router.navigate(routesliced as any)
     
    }
```

Comment: We have talk about that in the comments. It's a different thing he needed